# How to save the state of a generator function in python?

Tags: python, generator, state

I have a prime-yielder function called `xprimes(start,stop)` wich behaves like this:

```
>>> xpms = xprimes(2) #not specifying the stop yields primes forever.
>>> xpms.next()
2
>>> xpms.next()
3
>>> xpms.next()
5
>>> xpms.next()
7
>>> xpms.next()
11
```

And so on.
I'd like to know if it is possible to store the state of any generator function in a variable such as if this example happens, where both `xpms1` and `xpms2` were held about to yield `13`

```
>>> xpms1 = xpms; xpms2 = xpms;
>>> xpms1.next()
13
>>> xpms1.next()
17
>>> xpms1.next()
19
>>> xpms2.next()
13
```